# Can a DNS wildcard only be the leftmost part of a record?

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain, tinydns

I'm using TinyDNS, and have successfully used wildcard records of the form:

```
+*.<domain>:<ip>
```

(+ for A records.)

Can I also use:

```
+development.*.<domain>:<ip>
```

?

My intention is for all subdomains to have their development website point to our dev machine in one rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wildcard DNS records have a single "*" (asterisk) as the leftmost DNS label, such as `*.domain.com`. Asterisks at other places in the domain will not work as a wildcard, so neither `*development.domain.com` nor `development.*.domain.com` work as wildcard DNS records.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record)

Comment: It would indeed be nice if it was possible to do like that, but unfortunately not.